# Dynamic Spill-down Formula Fails to Spill

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, office365

In an Excel 365 environment, I attempt to insert a dynamic spill-down formula:

```
Sub WhyDoesThisFail()
    Range("A1").Formula = "=SEQUENCE(10)"
End Sub
```

Strangely I get:

[image]

There is a gratuitous ***@*** and no spill. (*If I enter the formula manually, I get the expected result.*)

Equally strangely, if I enter the formula as a `String` I get the expected result!

```
Sub WhyDoesThisWork()
    Range("A1") = "=SEQUENCE(10)"
End Sub
```

Why does `.Formula` fail?? Can anyone explain what's going on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.Formula2`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula2)

> In Dynamic Arrays enabled Excel, Range.Formula2 supercedes Range.Formula. Range.Formula will continue to be supported to maintain backcompatibility.

```
Sub WhyDoesThisFail()
    Range("A1").Formula2 = "=SEQUENCE(10)"
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks..................clearly I have much to learn.....................

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I just learned this myself.  I lucked into the correct google search.